# Can i use something like tunnel in vim?

Tags: vim, editor

For example:

If my current directory is /temp/src/com. And the file edited in vim is from /java/test.And now i want to add the path of the file to path environment. So if there is a cmd like `set path+=$(filepath)` in vim?

case 2:

Run `make` in terminal will start to compile a project, and it will out put logs about this compile. And now i want to read the outputed logs into vim using some command like `r !make`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Pull the path into the current Vim buffer:

> :r !echo \%PATH\%

Append to the path:

> :let $PATH="C:\Test" . $PATH

2) This question is ambiguous, because it depends on your makefile behavior.
If your Makefile simply print to the console, then, :r make should do the trick. 
If your make file actually writes to files explicitly, then there is no automatic way.
You'll have to write a custom vimscript function to pull in the logs.

1) Part 2
I do not know of what a way to do it in one line, but here's one way to achieve the functionality you want.

> :redir @a "redirect output to register a
>   :pwd
>   :redir END "stop redirecting
>   :let @a = substitute(@a, '\n', '', 'g') "remove the newlines
>   :let $PATH=@a .":". $PATH

You should be able to wrap this in a function if you need to use it often.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helps. The second issue has been solved. But the first question i haven't express clearly. I have known how to add a path. But what i haven't solved is how to add a path generate from a command. We all know `pwd` will print the current directory in vim. Then i doubt if i can add the `pwd` to path (Although it is already in path, i just want to clarify this problem). Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

1. You may reference environment variables using `$MYVAR` syntax. To set system environment variables use

   `let $MYVAR=foo`

   e.g.

   `let $PATH = "/foo" . $PATH`

   See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Environment_variables or [:help :let-environment](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3alet-environment)

   Then you may use [filename-modifiers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers) to get directory name of a file in a current buffer:

   `let $PATH = expand("%:p:h") . $PATH`
2. To read and parse compilation output in vim you might be interested to check [quickfix mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html)

   Use `:make` instead of `:!make`